# ZTE Score only booting to recovery

Tags: boot, zte-score

I have a *ZTE N788 MTS352 CDMA Mobile* unlocked to use any CDMA in India. Rooted it perfectly. Deleted unwanted APP, by mistake deleted one sys app "wall paper change"- after that mob. not working. when press combination volume up and power switch, following appears:

```
ANDROID SYSTEM RECOVERY <3E>
android system recovery utility
```

- reboot system now
- apply update from sdcard
- wipe data/factory reset
- wipe cache partition

If from combination Vol. down and power button - FTM  appears.

Now nothing happens other than rebooting while clicking "reboot system now"

any body can help me. I am in a remote village of India.